# selenium + Python запуск браузера с cookies

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Задача: запустить браузер Chrome, ввести логин и пароль, записать это в куки. И последующие открытия браузера подставлять эту куку. Вот код:

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\...\\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://site..../')

driver.find_element_by_name('USER_LOGIN').send_keys('.....')
driver.find_element_by_name('USER_PASSWORD').send_keys('<......>')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('checkbox').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('Login').click()
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))

driver.quit()

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
print(cookies)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\......\\chromedriver')

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://site.../")
```

Валится на этой строке: `driver.add_cookie(cookie)`
Вот с таким логом: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie`
Визуально: Открывается второй раз браузер и все. Ссылка не вводится.
В чем беда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот. Логика в этом куске неверная. Надо вот так:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\......\\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://site.../")
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
sleep(1)
driver.refresh()
```