# Selenium запомнить авторизацию

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cookie

Стоит задача, с помощью селениума залогиниться в телеграме, чтобы в следующие разы сразу уже открывалась авторизованная страница. Как это лучше всего организовать?
Я делал, как в дубликате вопроса, куки получаются пустыми, по какой-то причине, вот код:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://web.telegram.org')
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name('phone_number').send_keys('1234567')
sleep(1.5)
driver.find_element_by_name('phone_country').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('phone_country').send_keys('+7')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('login_head_submit_btn').click()
sleep(0.5)
a = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
a[1].click()
input()
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
driver.quit()
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
print(cookies)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get('https://web.telegram.org')
```

Выполняется авторизация и сайт ждет, пока я введу код, который пришел в приложение, код я ввожу вручную, в это время программа на строчке `input()` ожидает. После ввода кода авторизация успешно проходит, однако куки получаются пустыми.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [selenium + Python запуск браузера с cookies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951040/selenium-python-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%81-cookies)

Comment: @RomanKonoval для меня этот вариант не помог, куки пустые, вопрос исправил.